# Setting 2 attributes using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to set two attributes using attr() tag but it works fine in old jquery version 1.3.4 but doesn't work in new version 2.1.3. I am using Grider API and it has following `addRow()` function

```
 function addRow() {
        var tr = $(table).find('tr:not(.noedit):first').clone();
        addFormPos();

        if($(tr).find("input, select, textarea").length > 0) {
            $(tr).find("input, textarea, select").each(function(index, elem) {
                // Change the name of the fields
                var newName = '';
                if(config.formPos !== '') {
                    newName = elem.name.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/i, '[' + config.formPos + ']');
                }else {
                    newName = elem.name;
                }
                if(elem.type == 'checkbox' || elem.type == 'radio') {
                     $(elem).attr({'name': newName, 'checked': false})
                }else {
                     $(elem).attr({'name': newName, 'value': ''});
                }
                $(elem)
            });
            $(tr).find("input:radio, input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
        }
        if(cols[k] && cols[k].type == "" && cols[k].formula)
            $(tr).find("td:eq(" + cols[k].pos + ")").html('');
        if(config['countRow']) {
            var fila = parseInt($(table).find('tr:not(.noedit):last td:eq('+ config['countRowCol'] +')').html()) + 1;
            $(tr).find('td:eq('+ config['countRowCol'] +')').html(fila);
        }
        $(table).find('tr:not(.noedit):last').after(tr);
        // Register elements that fire events
        setEvents();
        for(var kk in cols){
            if(cols[kk].summary)
                calculateSummary(cols[kk].name);
        }
    }
```

I am facing issue in the following line of code

```
$(elem).attr({'name': newName, 'value': ''});
```

It doesn't set `value=""` in jquery 2.1.3 version but sets name correctly. Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

This doesn't work in `Oracle APEX v5.0` new theme. I am using the following API from github
[Grider.js](https://github.com/boriscy/grider)

Comment: what value are you using if it is not input it wont set value only input has value you can use `data-*` for that use. Can you add html mark up as well

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML to the question?

Comment: You can refer [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @guradio added entire function

Comment: select and textarea has no attribute value it is invalid use `data-value` instead you can still get it and set it just like that

Comment: This should work 
.attr({
    target:"nw", 
    title:"Opens in a new window"
});

Comment: can you try this: `$('#div').attr('newName','');`

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar  agreed with guradio  :-`select and textarea has no attribute value it is invalid use data-value instead you can still get it and set it just like that`

Comment: I have html as input

Comment: Please add html of table also

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps that's nothing to do with jQuery alone.

Consider this element in your HTML.

```
<p id="content">something here<p>
```

Use Vanilla JS to add an attribute to it.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('content');
elem.setAttribute("value","");
```

Inspect the `<p>` element. You will find the value attribute present but without any value.

```
<p id="content" value>something here</p>
```

Surprisingly, when you copy this HTML snippet from your dev tools by clicking "Edit as HTML", this will be the output.

```
<p id="content" value="">something here</p>
```

Seems like its just a browser trick only. It shouldn't effect any functionality.

Comment: Not sure if the person who downvoted actually tried running the steps.